# What is the recommended way to incorporate predefined data into spark structured streaming "rate-micro-batch" source?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am currently exploring Apache Spark Structured Streaming for a project that requires simulating streaming data for testing purposes. To achieve this, I'm using the "rate-micro-batch" source to generate a continuous stream of data. However, for my use case, I need to enrich this streaming data with predefined data from a static source, for example a CSV file.

The goal is to simulate a more realistic streaming scenario where each record from the "rate-micro-batch" source is associated with additional attributes pulled from the predefined dataset.

What is the easiest and most recommended way to achieve this integration of predefined data with the "rate-micro-batch" source?
Are there built-in functions in Spark that facilitate this kind of data enrichment for streaming sources?

I tried to modify the streaming data by injecting some fake values to simulate more complex scenarios. However, this method doesn't work well for me because it doesn't let me use specific, predefined data:

```
  val rateDF = spark.readStream
    .format("rate-micro-batch")
    .option("rowsPerSecond", "10")
    .load()

  val modifiedRateDF = rateDF
    .withColumn("type",
      when(col("value") % VALUE_DIVISION_FACTOR === 0, "update")
        .when(col("value") % VALUE_DIVISION_FACTOR === 1, "insert")
        .when(col("value") % VALUE_DIVISION_FACTOR === 2, "delete"))
    .withColumn("key",
      when(col("type") === "insert", col("value") + DELTA_TABLE_MAX_ID)
        .when(col("type") === "update", col("value"))
        .when(col("type") === "delete", col("value")))
    .withColumn("id", col("key"))
    .withColumn("col1", expr("concat('rs', key)"))
    .withColumn("col2", array("updated"))
    .withColumn("col3", array("updated"))
    .withColumn("modified_value", when(col("type") === "delete", lit(null)).otherwise(struct(
      col("id"),
      col("col1"),
      col("col2"),
      col("col3")
    )))
    .drop("value", "type", "id", "col1", "col2", "col3")
    .withColumnRenamed("modified_value", "value")
```